# Excel VBA web scaping element challenge

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to collect pricing data from a travel website.

Below is the HTML and I want to retrieve the number 2145.66 and put that in an Excel Cell.

```
<ul class="hotelresults"> 

<li class="image"><img src="http://images.libertytravel.com/shared/cpl/fcl/images/upload/suppliers/H/AUA/REM/img_148208_MEDIUM.jpg" width="120" onerror="this.src='/images/book.libertytravel.com/no-pic.gif';"></li>
<li class="detail">
<h4>Renaissance Marina Hotel &nbsp;<img src="http://static0.traveltek.net/images/book.libertytravel.com/1star.png" alt="Star"><img src="http://static0.traveltek.net/images/book.libertytravel.com/1star.png" alt="Star"><img src="http://static0.traveltek.net/images/book.libertytravel.com/1star.png" alt="Star"><img src="http://static0.traveltek.net/images/book.libertytravel.com/1star.png" alt="Star"></h4>
<span class="myTime"></span><span class="hotelPref"></span>
<h5>Aruba</h5>
<span id="desc_555_0.1">Experience a fresh twist on stay and play in a stylish, sophisticated atmosphere at the Renaissance Aruba Resort and Casino. </span><a href="/fusion/searchsinglehotel.pl?sessionkey=F5AFD4B1-782Cl4A8B-9B26-AC8EAE88C1E5&amp;chosenhotel=555_0.1&amp;chosenflight=617_0.0">See Details</a>
</li>
<li class="price">
    <script language="Javascript">
Event.observe(window, "load", function() {

$$('span.roomprice').each(function(element) {
         element.innerHTML = properrounding(element.innerHTML, 2);
     });

});
</script>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="roomsrow">
    <tr class="hide">
        <td colspan="3" class="sectionHeader">
            <a href="#" onclick="showmore('hotelDetails'); return false">
                <div id="hotelExpand">
                    <div class="plusMinus"></div>
                </div> Show/Hide extra room selections
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:none">

            <div id="hotelDetails" style="display:none">

                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">        
                    <tr class="hide">
                        <th align="left">Room Description</th>
                        <th align="right">Total Basket Cost</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    <script language="Javascript">
Event.observe(window, "load", function() {

$('rightprice_div_555_0.1_555:0').innerHTML = properrounding('2145.66', 2);
```

My code is as follows:

```
r = 0
c = 0

Set TDelements2 = .document.getelementsbyclassname("price")
l = TDelements2.Length

For i = 0 To l

MsgBox (TDelements2.Item(i).innertext)
MsgBox (i)
i = i + 0

Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = TDelements2.Item(i).innertext
r = r + 1
c = c + 0
Next
```

However, this in not returning the rate/number I am looking for.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: where is your code failing to do what you want? what results do you get when you loop through that and what do you expect?

Comment: MsgBox (TDelements2.Item(i).innertext) is where the code fails. I use the msgbox to see what returns before putting this in an excel cell. I was hoping to get the rate from the website returned in the msgbox.

Comment: Was "properrounding(" present anywhere else? You could split on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the `document.body.innerHTML` for that string. Let's say you were using `properrounding` to target the section of interest.

Using just the HTML as a guide, you would have

```
Debug.Print Replace(Split(Split(.document.body.innerHTML, " properrounding(")(2), ", 2")(0), Chr$(39), vbNullString)
```